Do we have any attack for (R)LWE with small public key, secret and error?
Suppose we have an (R)LWE setup $(a, a\cdot s + e)$ in the ring $R = Z[x]/(x^n + 1)$ with $n$ a power of two, $R_q$ is the ring modulo a prime $q$ and $R_p$ is a ring modulo a prime $p$ with $q >> p$. as an example we can pick $p = 3$ and $\log q = 29$. If $s \in R_2$ and $a \in R_p$ is LWE still hard given samples in the ring $R_q$? If not how can we estimate this and which attack is possible? We can take $e$ to be from any distribution with a bound, for example $e \xleftarrow{} U(R_p)$.

Strictly speaking, if you define $R_p$ to be the ring modulo $p$, then the product $a\cdot s$ between an element of $R_p$ and an element of $R_2$ doesn't make sense to begin with, and it surely cannot be regarded as an element of $R_q$. So for the question to make sense, let's say that, by $R_p$, you mean the set of elements of $R$ which have coefficients in $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$, and similarly for $R_2$.
In that case, unless $n$ is incredibly large, $a\cdot s + e$ has coefficients much smaller than $q$, so your samples are actually in $R$: it is an LWE problem without modular reduction, which can be solved with techniques like the least squares method. See e.g. this paper.

Thanks! It is still not clear to me if the error distribution must be bigger than $a$ distribution. In the paper results, if we plug the same variance for both, the success probability will decrease with $n$, so just to conclude, we need bigger $e$s but not too big, right?

You want the distribution of $a$ to be uniform in $R_q$ for (R)LWE. Otherwise you have some non standard problem that is likely to be broken, even if the secret and error vectors are fairly large. Another example is this attempt from 2013, with uniform $s$ and binary $a$, which was broken with linear programming techniques.
